# I want my JavaScript code to return "it is a leap year" but it is returning "not a leap year"

Tags: javascript

I want my JavaScript code to return "it is a leap year" but it is returning "not a leap year".

```js
function isLeap(year) {
  if (year % 4 === 0) {
    if (year % 100 === 0) {
      if (year % 400 === 0) {
        return 'it is a leap year';
      } else {
        return 'not a leap year';
      }
    } else {
      return 'It is a leap year';
    }
  } else {
    return 'not a leap year';
  }
}

console.log('2000: ', isLeap(2000));
console.log('2001: ', isLeap(2001));
console.log('2002: ', isLeap(2002));
console.log('2003: ', isLeap(2003));
console.log('2004: ', isLeap(2004));
```

Comment: `undefined` is not a leap year, try passing the function a value

Comment: can you please provide the numbers/examples of calls that are returning an unexpected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if( (year%4 == 0 && year%100 != 0) || (year%400 == 0) ) {
    return "It is a leap year";
}
else {
    return "not a leap year";
}
```

Comment: won't fix the problem if you don't pass the year into to function ... OP's logic is correct (verbose but correct) - besides `if (!(year%4) - !(year%100) + !(year%400))` is even more compact code :p

Comment: OP's logic is not right. It always prints "it's a leap year" when the year is divisible by 4, but not by 100. Regarding passing the year, that's too obvious.

Comment: You are right I got confused. And that's exactly the reason why he needs to write the code in a simpler way xD

Answer (score 4):

If you just call `isLeap();`, then the parameter `year` is `undefined`.
You have to pass the year you want to test in your function, e.g. like this: `isLeap(2020);`